# The type of the expression in the select clause is incorrect. Entity Farmework MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
 using (var db = new EntityDataModel())
            {
                var personresuls = (from personslist in db.tblPersons                                        
                                   select PersonList).ToList();
            }
```

this code shows the error 
The type of the expression in the select clause is incorrect.

Comment: drop the stack trace onto the question as it may contain the actual answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have spelled personslist wrong in the select.

Try this:

```
using (var db = new EntityDataModel())
{
    var personresuls = (from personslist in db.tblPersons                                        
                               select personslist).ToList();
}
```